# Amchart: How the period range is selected?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I'm a bit confused about how the last date is selected when we specify period.

In [this](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/making-stock-charts-period-selector-input-fields-read-only/) example when we choose `1 month` the end date is `27-07-2018` but when we choose `1 year` the end date `30-07-2018`

(Today is `27-07-2018`)

In case of `1 year` I lose three days as the start of the period becomes `30-07-2017` but not `27-07-2017`

I didn't find in documentation the way to specify start or end date for `periods`

Than you in advance

Comment: I see "From 27-07-2017 to 30-07-2018" in left pane (like 1 year **and** 3 days instead of 1 year)

Comment: You right. My fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely running into how the stock charts [data grouping](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/understanding-data-grouping-of-stock-chart/) is working with your data. By default, AmCharts groups your data into periods for performance, which can sometimes affect your period selector ranges. You can fix the period selector range output by setting [`extendToFullPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#extendToFullPeriod) to false in the top level of your stock chart object.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  extendToFullPeriod: false,
  // ...
})
```